# Python - How to add multiple reroute node between two NodeSocket?

Tags: python

Is it possible to add multiple reroute nodes between two `NodeSocket` links via python?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK socket nodes behave like all the other nodes when creating links with the API. Or do you mean that you want to ensure that the reroutes are located on the path of the existing link ?

Comment: want to ensure that the reroutes are located on the path of the existing link

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual way to do that because noodles may follow arcs depending on the "Noodle Curving" setting in themes (under Node Editor).

Further, the node drawing code doesn't produce information on where along the edge of the node the socket is.

The best you can do is use the source and destination's location, height, and width fields to estimate where the reroute should be placed between the two initial nodes.

Here's some code that outlines the idea of what you would want to try, placing a reroute between the Principled shader and Material output of an existing basic material on the active object:

```py
import bpy

node_tree = bpy.context.active_object.material_slots[0].material.node_tree

src_node = node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
src_socket = src_node.outputs["BSDF"]

dst_node = node_tree.nodes["Material Output"]
dst_socket = dst_node.inputs["Surface"]

def find_link(node_tree, src_node, src_socket, dst_node, dst_socket):
    for link in node_tree.links:
        if link.from_node != src_node: break
        if link.from_socket != src_socket: break
        if link.to_node != dst_node: break
        if link.to_socket != dst_socket: break
        return link
    return None

#link = find_link(node_tree, src_node, src_socket, dst_node, dst_socket)

#node_tree.links.remove(link)

reroute = node_tree.nodes.new(type="NodeReroute")
new_dst_socket = reroute.inputs[0]
node_tree.links.new(src_socket, new_dst_socket)
new_src_socket = reroute.outputs[0]
node_tree.links.new(new_src_socket, dst_socket)

src_edge = src_node.location + Vector((src_node.width / 2.0, 0))
dst_edge = dst_node.location - Vector((dst_node.width / 2.0, 0))

delta = dst_edge - src_edge

reroute.location = src_edge + delta / 2.0
```

If youi try it, you can see that because of the shape of the principled shader it doesn't work well.  It would work even less well on a collapsed shader.